# AV-H830 TV Tuner installation error

Tags: 14.04, tv, tv-tuner, video4linux

I have a problem with installation drivers for my TV Tuner AverTV Hybrid Volad HD H830.

After running the script, I get this output:

```
/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build found.
Verifying archive integrity...
Extracting archive...
Running installer...
Start to compile objects...
Failed to compile objects
cp -f prebuild.bak prebuild.o
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build  O=/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/avm-install/installer/KernToDemod.o
In file included from /tmp/avm-install/installer/CLGDT3305.h:11:0,
                 from /tmp/avm-install/installer/KernToDemod.h:4,
                 from /tmp/avm-install/installer/KernToDemod.c:1:
/tmp/avm-install/installer/osdep_dvb_2.h:4:26: fatal error: dvb_frontend.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
 #include "dvb_frontend.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [/tmp/avm-install/installer/KernToDemod.o] Błąd 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/tmp/avm-install/installer] Błąd 2
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Błąd 2
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
make: *** [default] Błąd 2
```

I have read, that I need to install V4L. So I am trying to build it and get another error:

```
******************
* Start building *
******************
make -C /usr/src/media_build/v4l allyesconfig
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu `/usr/src/media_build/v4l'
No version yet, using 3.13.0-24-generic
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/usr/src/media_build/v4l'
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu `/usr/src/media_build/v4l'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/media_build/linux'
Applying patches for kernel 3.13.0-24-generic
patch -s -f -N -p1 -i ../backports/api_version.patch
patch -s -f -N -p1 -i ../backports/pr_fmt.patch
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/drivers/media/usb/gspca/dtcs033.c b/drivers/media/usb/gspca/dtcs033.c
|index 5e42c71..ba01a3e 100644
|--- a/drivers/media/usb/gspca/dtcs033.c
|+++ b/drivers/media/usb/gspca/dtcs033.c
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
make[2]: *** [apply_patches] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/media_build/linux'
make[1]: *** [allyesconfig] Błąd 2
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/usr/src/media_build/v4l'
make: *** [allyesconfig] Błąd 2
can't select all drivers at ./build line 490.
```

Can you help me? I have no idea what should I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this solved it for me

[Compiling linuxtv fails when applying patch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449471/compiling-linuxtv-fails-when-appliying-patch)

you need to edit the diff file and remove a particular patch, since the underlying driver code isn't on the filesystem.